# Slow internet until I bring laptop to the router for a few seconds

Tags: networking, router, internet, internet-connection

I have a router placed in another room in 10 meters from my bedroom when I'm usually sitting with laptop connected to it by wi-fi.
Sometimes connection becomes very slow: even YouTube videos in 240p can be barely loaded and speedtest.net shows about 1 mbps download speed or less.
Recently I've noticed the strange thing: It's enough to bring my laptop next to the router for few seconds after that connection will be restored to my usual 70-100 mbps and speed will remain that fast even when I go back to the bedroom.
Can someone explain this thing?

Answer (score 0):

> It's enough to bring my laptop next to the router for few seconds
> after that connection will be restored to my usual 70-100 mbps and
> speed will remain that fast even when I go back to the bedroom.

Update the driver for the wireless card in the laptop. The existing driver may have some issues that a new driver will correct. Do that for sure.

Then update the firmware in the router. Improved firmware may be a better match for the new laptop wifi driver.